# computed.oneWay not working with Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an EmberData snapshot which I'd like decorate with a few additional attributes before handing over to the UI for presentation. This decoration will be setting "properties" of the Ember-Data record not actual attributes. It looks like this:

```
let foo = Ember.computed.oneWay(this.get('store').find('activity')); 
foo.map(item => {
    item.set('foobar', 'baz');
    return item;
}
```

I would then hope that `foo` would be the beneficiary of the promised record (it is) and the setting of the `foobar` property would be localized to the foo property (it's not, it seems to be globally scoped to the record's properties).

Answer (score 0):

As for me this is expected behavior.

1) `OneWay` means only you are not bind `set` method on `foo`. It used to work between properties of objects, but `this.get('store').find('activity')` is a just promise.

2) `foo` is `store.find()` result of `DS.RecordArray` type (assuming promise is resolved). So you are iterating on records returned and set `foobar` property on them.

Achieving your goal, you could decorate `activity` record by `component` (Ember 2.0 way) for UI presentation.

Comment: Do you know of a good example of the component decorator you refer to?

Comment: this helps me, as i remember in comments there is example of `data down action up`, i think it looks good for you. https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97

Comment: I don't see an example of the Decorator pattern here

Comment: I may use Ember's `ObjectProxy` but I had a feeling there was a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So far the only way I've been able to do this is using Ember's `ObjectProxy` like so:

```
const FooDecorator = Ember.ObjectProxy.extend({
    foobar: 'baz'
});    
let foo = Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.get('store').find('activity').map(item => {
        FooDecorator.create({content: item});
    });
}
```

This works but I thought I'd been hearing things about Object proxies not being a welcome part of Ember 2.0 roadmap so not sure if this approach is best. I'll keep this open for a few days before closing.